# Using a Class Function within then block

Tags: javascript, promise

Having some issues with Promises and Then blocks.

Basically I am unable to access `aFunction(x)` from the then block.

Why is this? My code looks like:

```
class myClass {

   aFunction(x) {
    ...
   }

   bFunction(y) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      request(options, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
          resolve(body.token)
        } else {
          console.log('ERROR: ' + err)
          return reject(false)
        }
      })
    }).then(function(res){
      this.aFunction(res)
    })
   }

}
```

And on a side note, do i actually need that promise block?

Comment: `this.aFunction(rest)` => `aFunction(res)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an arrow function to preserver the context:

```
.then(res => {
  this.aFunction(res)
});
```

Or you can pass the `aFunction` directly to `then` and possibly use `bind` to preserve the context.

```
.then(this.aFunction.bind(this));
```

Or you can use a variable to preserve the context:

```
var self = this;
...
.then(function(res){
  self.aFunction(res)
})
```

In this case:

```
.then(function(res){
    this.aFunction(res)
});
```

`this` no longer refers to the instance of your class, it refers to the anonymous function you pass as a parameter to the `then` function or to whatever context was set to it.

Comment: great that worls. However for my understanding why the context lost in the first place?

Comment: @userMod2 I've edited my answer to try to explain what is going on.

Comment: many thanks. Also - that promise - it it actyally required I felt it was in order to the then block?

Comment: @userMod2 No, it is not needed. You can call the `aFunction` function inside the `if` statement. You will still have to use the methods in my answer because the `if` statement is inside the anonymous function you pass as a parameter to `request`.

Comment: The last line is a bit inaccurate. `this` would never refer to that function itself. As indicated in [2.2.5](https://promisesaplus.com/#point-35) of the Promises/A+ spec, the handler is called with no `this`, so `this` would be `undefined` in strict mode or the global object in sloppy mode.

Comment: @JLRishe - sorry you mean using `var self = this` isnt ideal? Would you say the arrow function better?

Comment: @JLRishe Good to know. I've just gave it a try and it seems that `this` is set to `window`, at least that is the case on Chrome using this example: `new Promise(function(resolve){resolve();}).then(function(){console.log("this", this);})`

Comment: @userMod2 JLRise was just referring to the explanation at the end of my answer. Which of the examples in my answer you use depends on what you're trying to do and also on preference.

Comment: @Titus Yup, in a browser, `window` is the global object so that's what `this` would be in sloppy mode. You'll see it's `undefined` if you do this: `(function () { "use strict"; new Promise(function(resolve){resolve();}).then(function(){conso‌​le.log("this", this);}); })();`